# Edge not showing up after creation in OrientDB

Tags: graph-databases, orientdb

I create an edge like so

```
CREATE CLASS PumpUpE ABSTRACT EXTENDS E
CREATE CLASS Posted EXTENDS PumpUpE
CREATE EDGE Posted FROM (SELECT FROM User WHERE objectId="vjuQDNCOX4") to #13:491
```

It all looks fine in the OrientDB Studio
[image]

But my `Posted` class is still empty
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the answer taken from https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Troubleshooting#why-cant-i-see-all-the-edges:

**Why can't I see all the edges?**

OrientDB, by default, manages edges as "lightweight" edges if they have no properties. This means that if an edge has no properties, it's not stored as physical record. But don't worry, your edge is still there but encoded in a separate data structure. For this reason if you execute a select from Eno edges or less edges than expected are returned. It's extremely rare the need to have the list of edges, but if this is your case you can disable this feature by issuing this command once (with a slow down and a bigger database size):

```
alter database custom useLightweightEdges=false
```